# Best way of image drawing + event listening?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, drawing, gtk#

I need to draw a image representing a network equipment (switch , router) the items on that image ( ethernet cards ) would need to be listening for "clickable" onOver events.

I managed to draw a basic idea to test with using the drawing area but will not be able to implement listening events on it.

Any sugestions?

Best regards,
FR

PS: The test was drawn using a single context.

Edit: I'm using mono c# and it's a gtk# based application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using .NET (you tagged C# on this question so I think that's safe) have you considered using an `ImageButton` for the clickable items?  You would be able to define custom behavior for any event you care to wire up.

This is just a guess from what you've described, but it sounds like a user control would be a good repository for this project.  You can define the layout graphically while keeping the code closely associated with what will be utilizing it.

Comment: Sorry, my fault I'm using mono c# and it's a gtk# based application.

Comment: It's been a while since I last worked in mono, but the concept should translate.  If you need to handle mouseOver and Click events for a certain area of the screen, you can place a transparent control over that area (so that the background/lowest level image is visible) while gaining access to the desired events.  Just make sure that the transparent control has a screen order higher than the background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650252/gtk-mouse-event-in-drawing-area Found a question like this :-( the method there works, didn't find a question before. Sorry. Thank you for the sugestion and help.